Policies on undergraduate students taking graduate courses
I'm curious what policies are common at US universities around whether and when undergraduates can take graduate-level courses.
At previous institutions where I've studied and worked, it was possible for an upper-level undergraduate student (say, 3rd or 4th year) to enroll in graduate courses, and possibly count it toward their graduation requirements.  They had to have the consent of the instructor and/or their advisor, and meet certain other criteria, such as minimum GPA, but it was not an unusual occurrence for particularly strong students to do this.
At my current institution, it is much more restrictive.  Graduate courses are classified by their course number, with 500 and 600 level courses being "master's level" and 700 being "doctoral level".  Advanced undergraduates may take 500-level courses with the instructor's permission, but there is an official policy that they are not allowed to take 600 or 700 level courses, even if the instructor approves.  There is also a rule against counting 600 or 700 level courses toward the requirements for an undergraduate degree.  So even if everyone agrees that a particular student is prepared for the course (maybe better than the grad students) and would benefit from it, they still can't take it.
(The only exception to this policy is for undergraduate students who are going straight on to a graduate program at this same university, and have already been accepted into the grad program pending the completion of their undergraduate degree.  In such cases, they are allowed to take 600-level courses with consent of instructor, but 700-level courses are still off limits.)
I found this policy quite surprising when I first learned about it, but most others here seem to think it is reasonable and unexceptional.  The rationale usually given is that if undergrads were allowed to enroll in higher-level 600 and 700 grad courses, there might be a tendency to "water down" the course content to better accommodate them, to the detriment of the graduate program's quality.
So I am curious what policies are prevalent at other institutions.  Is it more common to have a policy that undergrads are allowed to take grad courses with appropriate permission, or not?  Quantitative data would be ideal, but answers based on sufficiently broad experience would also be helpful.

I find your policy to be unnecessarily strict. But all such policies can be made more rational if someone, such as the department head or dean, can sign off on an exception. But, do you just want data, or do you want support for a more rational (my words) policy?

Do you think there could be a chance that a few undergrads could fill the course and block the enrollment of a master's or ph.d student?

@Buffy: I think that's just it - the policy doesn't provide for any such exceptions.  It's true that there is a general procedure to petition for an exception to any academic policy of any kind, but it's an elaborate process that has to go up to the graduate dean, and I've never heard of anyone using it for this purpose.  And again, at other institutions it is a routine thing that can be approved at a much lower level.

@mkennedy: Unlikely.  Graduate students already have higher registration priority than undergrads (they're allowed to enroll in courses starting a few days earlier).  And at other schools where instructor consent is sufficient, I think there's usually an understanding that the instructor should only give that consent if they expect that space is available.

Is this a place where some courses get "crosslisted" as both a master's level course and a doctoral level course with more or less the same contents but perhaps different assessment criteria/activities?

@Anyon: We do have cross-listing between undergrad (4xx) and master's (5xx) courses as you say: same lectures, different assignments.  But we don't do master's/doctoral crosslisting; if there's a course that should be taken by both levels, it's usually numbered 6xx and the same assignments and criteria applied to both groups of students.

When I took a few grad classes as an undergrad there was no difference in the assignments. The professors may have shaded the curve a bit, but I was not aware of it and it did not seem so at the time.

You describe "...rationale usually given..." but I've never heard a colleague (in maths, at five schools) give that kind of rationale for why undergraduates should not be in graduate courses. Did your colleagues in the department make the rationale or did the College/University make the rationale? That will help guide your understanding.

We not only allow (sufficiently prepared) undergraduates to take graduate courses, we sometimes find that undergraduates are the best students in the class.

While I will answer, I will also down vote. The question asks for a survey of answers. We could be here forever (or at least as long as all universities/departments have their say).

@JeffreyJWeimer: I tried to clarify in the last paragraph that I'm not asking for individual "my institution does X" answers. I would prefer broad data, e.g. from an existing survey with a meaningful sample. But I'm not sure such data exists, so I'd also accept an answer from broad experience; somebody with knowledge of how this works at many institutions, not just their own.

Still a long haul, based on my broad experience.

I have to ignore your last paragraph to consider this an answer, but it is more about what makes policy necessary and what makes it rational, rather than whether it is "common".
Large institutions need policies to avoid chaos. Without policies every case is individual and needs individual resolution. That can lead to unfairness. Policies mitigate that. The rules in such policies cover the common and typical cases.
But one characteristic of universities is that every student is different and one occasional encounters exceptional cases; Norbert Wiener for example. If a policy allows no exceptions then it will be unfair to some.
You already make an exception at the 600 level with "permission of the instructor". That may be fine for that level, but the next "Norbert" may need a higher level exception for a higher level course. If you can allow for that, then the policy returns to rationality.
A dean, say, can have a set of guidelines to help judge such exceptions. Those might involve the student's history, or the instructor's load, or whatever. But those can't be completely firm or they would be part of the policy. Again, the possibility of exceptions for exceptional cases. My personal view is that they should be somewhat permissive, but only "somewhat".
I once had to ask the dean for an exception to a policy of a rather different kind. He asked me to justify my request, which I did to his satisfaction and it made my path to graduation a bit easier. But I had to ask, and I had to provide justification.
If an educational institution lacks the possibility of exceptions to policies, then the faculty as a whole, can work to form better policies and/or draft an "exception policy" and lobby the administration to adopt it. Faculty associations of various kinds have been known to do that and actually have considerable moral/ethical power in such things.

Where I work it is as simple as "having an approval of the (graduate) course instructor", which makes perfect sense to me.
As to "the marginal cost of enrolling undergraduates is next to 0, except the professor has to do more work", this is outright false if you talk about real science and not some blah-blah-blah. There are not many undergraduate students that are ready to take the advanced courses in such subjects (I teach mathematics), so the pool of qualified candidates is always very small, and if you allow somebody unqualified to enter a high level course, it will result in an utter headache and disappointment for both the student and the instructor. I should say that I have had graduate classes in which the best student was an undergrad (as well as undergraduate classes in which the best student was still in high school), but those were exceptions, not the rule.

Let's ask what prohibits undergraduates from taking graduate courses.
In those cases where a course is required in a program of study for an accredited undergraduate degree, a decision on whether to disallow the undergraduate to register instead in a graduate course depends on the administrative accreditation rules. Accreditation guidelines could disallow it institutional wide. It could be disallowed by prohibitions for discipline-specific cases. By example, suppose that course Topic at the undergraduate level is required by accreditation to cover A, B, and C. Absent extenuating circumstances, the student cannot take Advanced Topic at the graduate level when it covers A, B, and D (but not C). To be clear, this restriction is not specifically prohibiting that an undergraduate student substitutes Advanced Topic for Topic because Advanced Topic is at a graduate level and not an undergraduate level, it is prohibiting the substitution of courses that do not cover the required content.
Absent accreditation rules, the next level of prohibition to prevent undergraduates from taking graduate courses should likely be found by reviewing course guidelines at the department level. For example, a graduate course may have its own set of pre-requisite requirements, and the pre-requisites may be "hard", meaning no exceptions are allowed.
After this, the rules are as per whatever administrative unit decides that they will be for whatever administrative reasons they want to give.
Exceptions to the above can be covered by extenuating circumstances. With accreditation, paperwork may be required.
Finally, absent anything else, the only thing that should limit an undergraduate student from taking a graduate course is their own desire and finances.
In summary, presuming that the guidelines from accreditation agencies only limit by content not by level, you have a long haul to ask every department in every institution what guidelines they have that prohibit undergraduates from taking graduate courses, and then asking why those rules are as they are.

Reasonable guesses, but not applicable in my case.  I found our accreditor's rules, and they specifically allow for the possibility of undergraduates taking graduate courses.  (B.1.c: "An institution may allow well-prepared advanced students to substitute its graduate courses for required or elective courses in an undergraduate degree program...").

And I've personally been the instructor of a graduate course which a well-prepared and eager undergraduate could not take despite my consent.  My department has no policies against this; they are set at the university level.  The course in question had no formal prerequisites, and in any case, prerequisite course requirements are always waivable by the instructor here.  Our department has no discipline-specific accreditation.

I would, however, be interested to know if there are any accrediting bodies that forbid this.  If someone knows of one, it would be a lot easier than me trying to search all of them.

@NateEldredge  My edit explains how accreditation limits the ability to substitute courses in a program of study. Outside of this, the rules for what can or cannot be taken are set by the university, the college, the department, or the course itself. These are not "reasonable guesses". These are from experiences working in two disciplines, across 30+ years, in two accrediting agencies teaching across 20+ different courses at undergraduate and graduate levels.

@NateEldredge ... "...  and then subsequently count those same courses ..." Which means, the substitution of the graduate course should if not must only occur when the graduate course will be used to continue the education at the next level. Been there. Done this one too. Just recently in fact.

Where I work (not in US) it is no longer allowed.  The government subsidizes the cost of education and graduate courses earn more per students than undergraduate classes: the logic is that grad courses have lower enrolment so the actual cost of resources to run the course is higher on a per-student basis.
You can easily see where this goes: this created an incentive for universities to enrol upper year undergrads in grad. courses, as the marginal cost of enrolling undergraduates is next to 0, except the professor has to do more work (aka mark more copies, read more essays etc).  For the universities the subsidy differential must have been worth it.
